# Mapping a gRPC repeated field of type enum to a c# record list property with the same enum type

Tags: c#, enums, type-conversion, grpc

I have a gRPC proto file with a message schema like this:

```
message FilterRequestDto {
    string AccountId = 1;
    repeated ComponentType ComponentTypes = 2;
    repeated string Inverters = 3;
}
```

where "ComponentType" is an **gRPC enum** like this:

```
enum ComponentType {
    INVERTER = 0;
    BATTERYSTORAGE = 1;
}
```

In my .net application, I would like to map an incoming gRPC request of type message FilterRequestDto to a record of type FilterDto, which looks like this:

```
public record FilterDto
{
    public string AccountId { get; init; }
    public List<string>? Inverters { get; init; }
    public List<ComponentType>? ComponentTypes { get; init; }
}
```

where "ComponentType" is an **c# enum** like this:

```
public enum ComponentType
{
    Inverter,
    BatteryStorage,
}
```

For the Inverters i managed the parsing, but unfortunately i can't figure out the conversion for the ComponentTypes.

My mapping function looks like this:

```
public static FilterDto ToFilterDto(this FilterRequest request)
{
    return new FilterDto
    {
        AccountId = request.AccountId,
        Inverters = Enumerable.ToList<string>(request.Inverters).ToList(),
        ComponentTypes = ????
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried to answer, but it isn't clear what the blockage is in the question: the code-gen *already* emits pretty much what you're after. If I've missed something in the question, please clarify - happy to try to help more.

Comment: Actually, there are ways to talk JSON in gRPC: https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-with-json/ .. I used postman as a grpc client in that particular example, that's where the JSON notation came from. But yeah you were right about the list of component types :) Anyhow i removed that fragment in order to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *should* work with just:

```cs
public static FilterDto ToFilterDto(this FilterRequestDto request)
    => new FilterDto {
            AccountId = request.AccountId,
            Inverters = request.Inverters.ToList(),
            ComponentTypes = request.ComponentTypes.Select(
                 static comp => (ComponentType)comp).ToList(),
        };
```

The `static comp => (ComponentType)comp` is a no-op conversion that effectively just changes the declared enum type, since the values match.

As an aside: if you wanted to skip this step, your existing model should also be wire-compatible with the code-first gRPC approach using protobuf-net, just by adding some decoration:

```cs
    [ProtoContract]
    public record FilterDto
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string AccountId { get; init; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public List<string>? Inverters { get; init; }
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public List<ComponentType>? ComponentTypes { get; init; }
    }
```

you'd have to use a code-first service, too; [more info](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted) - but something like:

```
[Service("Some.Qualified.ServiceName")]
public interface ISomeService {
    async Task<SomeResponseType> SomeMethodAsync(FilterDto request,
        CallContext context = default);
}
class MyService : ISomeService {...your server implementation...}
```